# Can't access models from seperate: ImportError: no module named "HealthNet.ActivityLog"

Tags: python, django

I've been working on a way to log the activity of a system for a school project in Python 3.4 and Django 1.9. I am currently trying to import a models.py file from my ActivityLog app into other applications in my HealthNet project to save the activity. The IDE I'm using (Pycharm), is telling me that my code is correct but I get the this error whenever I try to makemigrations/migrate/runserver:

> ImportError: No module named 'HealthNet.ActivityLog'

Here is my file setup:

```
HealthNet
    ActivityLog
        Migrations
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    Appointments
        Migrations
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
HealthNet
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```

I'm trying to import models.py from ActivityLog into views.py from Appointments.

Here's my code from models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Log(models.Model):
    logTime = models.DateTimeField()
    logEvent = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.logEvent
```

This is the import statement from views.py in the Appointment package, which is the line that the error is tracing back to:

```
from HealthNet.ActivityLog.models import Log
```

And here is my list of installed apps in my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Appointment.apps.AppointmentConfig',
    'User.apps.UserConfig',
    'ActivityLog.apps.ActivitylogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ActivityLog.models import Log
```

'ActivityLog' and 'Appointments' are apps. So add 'ActivityLog' and 'Appointments' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

For eg:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    'Appointment.apps.AppointmentConfig',
    'User.apps.UserConfig',
    ..........................
    .........................
    'ActivityLog',
    'Appointments',
    ]
```

Try this. It will work.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve this issue via the solution you provided us. The issue we ran into was that Pycharm was throwing a fit with the import statement, telling us that it couldn't find the ActivityLog directory. Thanks again!